# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x^2+\sin^2x } dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The integral  $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x^2+\sin^2x } dx$$ admits
a nice closed form. The question is: How to evaluate it by hand.

Comment: Substitute $u = x\csc(x)$.

Comment: Are you sure it converges?

Comment: The integral is imroper but it is convergent, one has to take limit of the anti-derivative as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(x-i\sin(x))
&=\frac{1-i\cos(x)}{x-i\sin(x)}\\
&=\frac{x+\sin(x)\cos(x)}{x^2+\sin^2(x)}+i\frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{x^2+\sin^2(x)}
\end{align}
$$
Taking the imaginary part of both sides
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac1{2i}\log\left(\frac{x-i\sin(x)}{x+i\sin(x)}\right)
&=\frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{x^2+\sin^2(x)}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\int\frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{x^2+\sin^2(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
=\frac1{2i}\log\left(\frac{x-i\sin(x)}{x+i\sin(x)}\right)+C
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{x^2+\sin^2(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\frac1{2i}\log\left(\frac{1-i}{1+i}\right)\\
&=\frac\pi4
\end{align}
$$

Comment: $\frac1{2i}\log\left(\frac{x-i\sin(x)}{x+i\sin(x)}\right)
=-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}x\right)$

Answer (score 18):

$$ I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x-x \cos x}{x^2+\sin^2 x}  dx= - \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\frac {x\cos x -\sin x}{x^2}}{1+(\frac{\sin x}{x})^2}dx=
-\int_{1}^{0} \frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: Isn't $-\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}=-\frac\pi2$? The integral should be $-\int_1^0\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}$.

Comment: @robyjohn, Thanks for point it our. I have edited it now.